# upgraded to bookworm now ethernet isn't working how to downgrade the kernel?

Tags: networking, pi-4, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi 4, and I upgraded it to bookworm, but eth0 the main ethernet adapter disappeared.

I had 6.1.29 and it upgraded to 6.1.39 but it doesn't seem to have the bcm2711 driver for the Pi 4?

For some reason the built-in  wifi won't connect due to no power or wireless power off option.  The ability to configure wifi from raspbi-config fails with a wpa_supplicant error.

I only wish to restore the kernel the rest is fine.

Comment: As there is no Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm release and the latest supported kernel in Bullseye is 6.1.21 you have obviously installed testing software - expect problems. Just restore from your backup.

Comment: restore the backup you made before upgrading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have 3 active services.

I decided to use a spare SD card with a fresh raspberry Pi OS.
I upgraded it to bookworm, and this time everything worked.

I attached the only SD card to a USB card reader, and mounted it.  I copied the required config files to the new SD card.

Enabled and started the services and the network card just came back and stayed this time.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi github firmware repo contains a compiled kernel and all the other stuff from the boot directory.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master

The current kernel version as of a few days ago, though, is 6.1.39.  Fortunately, this means the previous kernel is only one commit back.  As far as I'm aware, there's no way to directly `git clone` a previous commit, but you can download a relatively shallow version of the repo (a non-shallow version of that will be very large), then rollback:

```
> git clone --depth 2 https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git
```

That will likely take a few minutes, not sure how big but be sure to have 100   MB available.  Then you can view the previous commit w/ `git log`. A more complete list can be viewed on github:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/commits/master

From which it can be seen that the one before this is labelled '9de4cec'; if you then click the copy button next to it you get the full hash.  From inside the directory created by clone, apply that with:

```
git reset --hard c88873d154455b2c254a2bfbb2be8c1b7
```

Then you just need to copy the kernel onto the boot partition *and the modules* (see top level "modules" directory of the repo) into `/lib/modules/` in the root filesystem.  They may or may not still be there from before your upgrade, as it is normal practice with RpiOS to delete all old versions.

You can boot a Pi without the modules installed but there will be reduced functionality.

Comment: sorry the pi doesn't have internet.

Comment: You don't need to do this with the Pi running.  You can access the first partition from any computer; the reason I mentioned that "You can boot a Pi without the modules installed" is that I am aware some people have trouble accessing the second partition from their windows box etc.